# Firebase App Distribution - Could not find APK after renaming it

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

Note: this only occurs after upgrading Firebase App Distribution Gradle plugin to 3.0.0 or newer.

Hi there,

We have in our project a gradle task to rename the apk file after generating it:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def fileName = "newApkName.apk"
        outputFileName = new File("../../", fileName)
        project.logger.info("APK file destination: ${outputFileName}")
    }
}
```

And here is the Firebase App Distribution task

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
    artifactType = "APK"
    testers = "testers"
    serviceCredentialsFile = project.buildscript.sourceFile.parent + "/firebase-app-distribution.json"
}
```

After launching `./gradlew appDistributionUploadStagingDebug` the task fails giving a "Could not find an APK file for this variant for App Distribution" error.

I have tried setting the `artifactPath` to the `outputFileName` generated by the rename task, but it does neither find it.

As I mentioned before, if I downgrade Firebase App Distribution gradle plugin to 2.2.0 it works like a charm (without need to set `artifactPath`), but not in newer versions.

Has anyone encountered this error? Thanks in advance.